# jQuery ON method sub tag issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found inserting issue in Chrome and IE in FF working well

I have next code that change classes name

```
 jQuery(document).on("mouseout", ".buttonStyleOver", { className: "buttonStyle" }, ChangeClass);
    jQuery(document).on("mouseover", ".buttonStyle", { className: "buttonStyleOver" }, ChangeClass);

    function ChangeClass(e) {
            var el = e.srcElement || e.target;
            jQuery(el).attr("class", e.data.className);        
    }
```

and I have next HTML part (please don't critic it I know this is bad style)

```
<button id="RunItButton" class="buttonStyle" type="button" style="vertical-align:middle;padding-right:5px;height:25px"><div class="cmRunIt">Run It</div></button>
```

in IE and Chrome event also change *class="cmRunIt*" to buttonStyleOver how to fix it ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you understand your problem, add a console.log :

```
var el = e.srcElement || e.target;
console.log(el);
```

You will see that some times `el` is not your button but the div ! Why do you use e.srcElement ?

Try with :

```
function ChangeClass(e) {
  jQuery(this).attr("class", e.data.className);        
}​
```

And marius is right, unless you need live events, you should use hover.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just do something like this?

```
$("#RunItButton").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("buttonStyleOver");
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass("buttonStyleOver");
});
```

or:

```
$("#RunItButton").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("buttonStyleOver");
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("buttonStyleOver");
});
```